# using shutil.move() I accidentally renamed my desktop folder to cat.jpg

Tags: windows-7, rename, move, python-3.6, shutil

while messing around with shutil and os modules(working on a tutorial exercise). I accidentally moved my desktop folder to an image format type called cat.jpg which doesn't exist anymore, I wasn't trying to move but I was trying to rename the image using shutil.move() when I forgot to type the image's name after its path .I actually managed to fix it after about an hour of googling  I recreated a folder and named it desktop then I restored it using previous versions.However, my question is where did the image(cat.jpg) and the original desktop folder go? I searched the whole computer without finding it. here's my code:

```
shutil.move("c:\\users\\nate\\desktop","cat.jpg")
```

which output:

```
'cat.jpg'
```

Comment: On the face of it, that command would delete the file `cat.jpg` and rename the desktop folder to be named `cat.jpg`.  Unless you deleted it, the folder should still be there, with its new name.

Comment: I checked but there was nothing there I even searched the whole PC with nothing  in it that name

Answer (score 0):

I found the desktop folder in the Python folder and its named desktop.jpg but it's still an actual folder containing all the file that I had .However, when I tried to delete it, I got a message saying that the file is shared in the name cat.jpg and asking me to be sure .so anyways just wanted to tell that so anybody facing the same problem will know where to look and what to do .